# passing value to inner function not working

Tags: javascript

I have a simple scenario in which i loop over an array then based on each element of array i create an object and pass it to another function which is defined inside another function.but the value from outermost function is not being passed.

```
// function1() returns an array

 function1().forEach(function (el) {
        var info = {};
        info.age = el

        function2('somearg',function(){
            fn3(info); //--------?? this info value is not being passed
        })
        console.log(info) //------?? it works here

    })
```

EDIT:

```
function2(node, func) {node.onclick = func;} //takes an arument and a function
fn3(info){ console.log(info)} //for test
```

Comment: let info instead of var info

Comment: are you shure you actualy call function passed to function2?

Comment: @MaciejKozieja yes, i have set tested it using alert but it gives a random object `{'istrusted:true`}

Comment: please show fn3, mamy you are missing named argument and it's using global value

Comment: Can you please post some details about `function2` and `fn3` as well?

Comment: Umm, that approach should work.

Comment: `istrusted` is a property commonly found in event objects. Please post a version of your code that is closer to what you're actually doing, it seems you're setting event handlers and getting something wrong in the process.

Comment: This edit is not helpful. The arity of `function2` was already clear. What does it *do* with the function it receives?

Comment: @MátéSafranka yes yes yes, i am trying to set onclick event of  an element inside function2()

Comment: @Tushar added details  of other functions

Comment: @anekix Please read the SO guidelines on how to post Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples or we will have to close this question as it's not taking us anywhere: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MátéSafranka i am correcting this

Answer (score 0):

You'd better refactor your code to something like this. I know, that it's not exactly what you are asking about, but I suppose it may help you. 
I assumed, that you want to add some event listeners or s-th like this to your elements.

```js
function function1() {
  return [18, 20, 30]
}

function fn3(info){ 
  console.log(info)      
} 

function addListener (fn) {
  return function (el) {
    console.log('Added callback',fn, el);
    //add event listener here, or whatever you want with fn
    //el.addEventListener('click')
  }
}

function getInfo(el) {
    return {
      age: el
    }
  }

const addListenerFn3 = addListener(fn3);      
  
let infoArray = function1().map(getInfo)
  
infoArray.forEach(addListenerFn3)
```

If your function1 returns not an array, but array-like object, you should transform it into array to be able call .map() on this. Feel free to ask questions to my answer or maybe you could add more details about problem you are trying to solve. I just want to encourage you to split your code into smaller functions which are easy to test and to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var info;
   [1,2,3].forEach(function (el) {
        info = {};
        info.age = el;

        function2('somearg',function(){
            fn3(info); 
        });
        console.log(info) ;

    });
   function function2(node, func) {node.onclick = func();} 
function fn3(info){ console.log(info);} 
</script>
```